To be unemployed for the RTDa in Italy
I'm Research assistant in Turkey, I'll apply for RTDa position in Italy. I will try to take sabbatical and then unpaid leave from my university in Turkey to apply for RTDa but i heard that Italy does not accept that,the position is not compatible with any other position as employee of any other university, in Italy or abroad. It is my first working experience in abroad and RTDA conntract is only for 3 years, so I'm not sure about resigning. Is that information true? SO do i have to resign to apply for rtda according to Italian laws?

See: https://internationaltalents.art-er.it/researchers/moving-to/career-paths-italian-research

When you're on unpaid leave, are you an employee?

Yes but when I take unpaid leave, I will not have any duties related to the university, even though I am a university employee.

Just to be sure I understand what you are asking, you want to take unpaid leave for 3 years from you university while working in Italy?

I have no idea about what RTDa actually is, but would imagine that what they care about is whether or not you are an "active employee", i.e., whether you are drawing two salaries. I can't imagine they'd care if you had an inactive position somewhere.

@JackRed sabbatical leave for the first year, unpaid leaves for other years. İn saabbatical leave, i can take my salary from my uni., but i will not have any responsibility. Because this is type of leave for academic research in abroad.

@WolfgangBangerth i thought the same like you. I will be inactive employee for 3 years.
